# Messages with accented characters between PHP and Android

Tags: php, android

Good night, people.

I'm having an annoying problem here that I can't figure out what to do. I have tried some solutions that I found here but nothing works.
I have an API written in PHP to make the bridge between my Android application and the database on my server. 
I have an EditText field in which the user can input a text and then this text must be stored at the server database. The problem is if this text contains any special characters (á, ã, ç, ...) it doesn't works.

If the user sends the word "avião", for example, in the database is recorded only "avi".

But I have reasons to think that the problem is on the PHP API or in the Android. I made a test: I made my API return the message sent (through POST Method) so I could use Log.d to debug it on LogCat. And turns out it returns 'null'.

On my HtppURLConnection I have this:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
```

And on the .php of my API I have

```
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
```

Can anyone figure out this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the database charset?

Comment: utf8_general_ci.
Another reason for me to think the problem is not in the database is because I have an HTML page to test my API functions, and if I test this function, that my Android app uses, it works regardless of the accents

Comment: Yep, you got me, I'm at a loss. utf8_general_ci is fine for accented characters so that shouldn't be problematic, my concern is that you are receiving a NULL value to your Log.d when debugging, yet the database still receives [in part] some of the data. I'll have to think more of where it should be but I would recommend looking into the bridge between the android device and the php server.

Comment: Ohgodwhy, if this helps: When I remove the meta tag to set the charset=utf8 on my HTML, then I have the same problem on the php: $_POST['message'] == null for any accented message. I will check that bridge better... Thx hmm

Comment: By the way, my API return JSON encoded data. I changed the PHP reader to application/json, but still, same error :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things may be happening here.

PHP to android: Make sure your PHP script file is encoded in UTF-8 as well. Make sure you are using the PHP function **json_encode** to encode the JSON response (and not writing the JSON response on your own). The *null* response sometimes occurs because there are some chars that were not correctly encoded in JSON.

Android to PHP: If nothing is working, you can try to **java.net.URLEncoder.encode("str", "UTF-8")** on Android side and **urldecode** on PHP side.

Sorry, I would comment on your question before posting an answer, but I have not enough reputation yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, man. Yes, I am printing the json like 'echo json_encode('debug' => $_POST['message'])' in the example that is returning null. In my Android, as I said, I have the content-type and charset sets for the POST method. And in my PHP I have the header as json and charset sets. Still didnt work. I will try the encoder, although I think it should be simplier. Thanks anyway, I will give a return if it worked... :)

Comment: It turned out it solved! I only set all my parameters with URLEncoder.encode() and changed nothing on PHP side. It worked fine. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hi Joao, are you decoding and encodign again the values you have in your $_POST to make possible the communication wit your app? I think I am facing the same problem than you but I am not able to solve it.